# Using Decorator Pattern with an ASP.NET (non-MVC) page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms, decorator

I've only recently started to develop in ASP.NET, though I've been using C# for several years now. My first approach to ASP.NET was using MVC 4, but now I find myself working on a project that uses plain ASP.NET pages. I'm at a loss as to how the general framework works.

Specifically, I have no idea how to implement the Decorator Pattern in an ASP.NET page. I have a Product.aspx page and I have to add a feature to it. I thought that Decorator Pattern would be best based on the task requirements, and I immediately figured out how I would use it in MVC, since the actual logic that is executed lies in the Controller Action: there I would instantiate my decorator object.

But I have no idea how to do it in ASP.NET. As far as I can see, when the browser requests Product.aspx "something" creates an object of class Product (derived from Page), and then it's too late to decorate it.

Is it therefore possible to decorate a whole ASP.NET page (not just an object used by the code behind)? How would I do that?

Comment: Webforms is more of an event driven model rather than MVC pattern so I'm not convinced decorator is the way to go with this. Are you familiar with the [page life cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.ASPX#additional_page_life_cycle_considerations). Without any specifics on what you want to do it's hard to help.

Comment: @Liam, thanks for the document: it's an interesting read, but it doesn't really clarify the subject at matter. In short, I need to show a showcase section in the page, based on a configuration file: the showcase section may even not be there. Additionally, it would be preferrable to be flexible, so that multiple showcases could be implemented in the future. Usually this seems the perfect case for Decorator; I'm starting to doubt whether this is good in a Webforms project.

Comment: Implement your showcase section as a user control that inputs your configuration, and decorate this user control on code behind using the configuration. You can create an abstract showcase web user control and override your methods on concrete showcase implementations.. or something like that

Comment: Thanks @Mecek, I did consider that solution, but I would love to make the regular page decoration-agnostic (I'm not sure I'll manage to do that 100% however). Suppose that a future decoration calls for a custom form in a different part of the page, and another one for a showcase with a search filter: the regular page would have to know about all of the possible decorations, which I'd rather avoid.

Comment: @Liam, not really... I'm asking how to apply the Decorator Pattern on a whole page. I agree that a solution involves applying the DP on controls, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not exactly sure what you wanna decorate, but;

You can create an HttpHandler that lets you do your work on a particular request as follows

```
public class MyHttpHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (context.Request.RawUrl.Contains("product.aspx"))
        {
            // may be you can execute your decorate business here
        }
    }

    public bool IsReusable { get { return false; } }
}
```

Or may be you can use Global.asax 's OnBeginRequest event like as follows

```
public class Global : HttpApplication
{
    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code that runs on application startup
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        AuthConfig.RegisterOpenAuth();
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

        base.BeginRequest += OnBeginRequest;
    }

    private void OnBeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.RawUrl.Contains("product.aspx"))
        {
            //execute your business here..
        }
    }
```

Comment: this doesn't describe anything to do with the decorator pattern? Where's your decoration?

Comment: @Liam: he has not shown the actual decoration, but the answer goes straight to the point of telling me *where* I could implement the decoration, which is basically what I asked.

Comment: In this answer there is not a decorator implementation, I had no idea what and where to decorate before the comment below the question. This is more accordingly to the question, where to implement request specific code instead of from inside the page..

Answer (score 1):

First of all, according to  your comment below the question, I can say that you should implement your showcase as a web user control (ascx)

You can decorate your ShowCase as follows,

```
public partial class ShowCase : System.Web.UI.UserControl, IShowCase
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){}
    public void ApplyConfiguration(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public interface IShowCase
{
    void ApplyConfiguration(IConfiguration configuration);
}

public abstract class Decorator : IShowCase
{
    protected IShowCase ShowCase;

    protected Decorator(IShowCase showcase)
    {
        ShowCase = showcase;
    }

    public virtual void ApplyConfiguration(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        ShowCase.ApplyConfiguration(configuration);
    }
}

public class ShowCaseDecoratorA : Decorator
{
    public ShowCaseDecoratorA(IShowCase showcase) : base(showcase){ }

    public override void ApplyConfiguration(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        base.ApplyConfiguration(configuration);
        //depending on the configuration, do something..
        ShowCase.Visible = false;
    }
}

public interface IConfiguration
{
    //configuration
}
```

Then, from inside the page that uses ShowCase user control, you do something like this,

```
public partial class _Default : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IConfiguration configuration = ConfigurationFactory.Get();
        new ShowCaseDecoratorA(this.ShowCase).ApplyConfiguration(configuration);
    }
}
```

I hope this gives you some inspiration..

Comment: Sorry that I'm splitting the discussion between the comment to the question and this comment. My previous point about how the page needs to know where the control goes may be wrong, because I am probably missing something. In your code example, is `ShowCase` instantiated as an element of the page? Or can I add it to the DOM (I know the DOM only exists for client-side applications, but for lack of a better term) where I want programmatically? If the latter were true, I could create as many extensions as I wish without altering the regular page.

Comment: ShowCase is instantiated in the page that uses it. It is a server side control that is rendered on server side and printed on where you located the control's tag in aspx page. For example, in case of that ShowCase shouldn't be printed to the response html, you can change its visibility from server side within your decorator and it won't be rendered. You had better read a little about using custom web user controls in web forms. I think it fits your issue here.

Comment: You're right: I need to learn more about user controls. But I think you're missing my main point (I led you a bit astray with my last comment, probably). Put aside ASP.NET and the technology specifics; from a conceptual point of view, I'm trying to decorate the page, NOT a control in the page. 

What I was saying before is that I would like it so that the regular page doesn't even know it could have a showcase or a form or whatever; and make it so that the additional components are all under the responsibility of an external object (the Decorator?).

Comment: With Custom Controls, I could decide that somewhere there has to be a ShowCase control, and then I'll decide which _derived class_ of ShowCase I should instantiate. No need to decorate the showcase: it will either be there and be blue, or be there and be red, or not be there at all - I don't need it to be usually blue but under certain circumstances also have a red stripe.

Also, with a custom control, the "placeholder" base control would always be there, even if there's just a couple of cases where it is actually needed.

Comment: Yes you do not need to use a custom control also you can implement a DataTransferObject like a model in MVC. Your product page has a property of Dto and you can use DataTransferObject instead of a webUserControl and you can use that Dto in your page's aspx code with inline serverside codes. If you want to execute your decoration business out of a specific page, you can add a master page and derive all your showcase included pages from that masterpage and execute decoration busines from masterpage's code behind.